# Tagging system similar to the one used in this site

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, tagging

i need to implement a tagging system looking exactly like the one we are using now. I'm new to the web developing so i'm having a few problems and i would like to start from an example but i can't find one.

In particular i would need the frontend part that, i suppose, parse an xml received from the server and print it like those cool squares with the tag in it. I don't need something exactly like this, an example of something similar would suffice.

Comment: Start with your database design, then the data structure, then the display.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use or supposed this data to be sent as xml ? do u save it in xml in the begining ? i suppose you should save your data in database . and create a table for every unique tag and then create a bridge bettween the posts table and the tag table containing every post with every tag linked to it .

Comment: i'm totally new to javascript and ajax, i have no clue how the interaction between javascript and php should work but i learnt it can use xml and i supposed it could work that way.

Comment: aha , so you have a design and javascript issues , this link should help you to use xml and javascript " AJAX " : [w3schools_php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_xml.asp) . do some little changes and you will get live tagging system

Comment: mmm nope, i studied on those examples but it's not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Tag plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/tags) by [CakeDC](http://cakedc.com/eng/downloads/view/cakephp_tags_plugin)? Might save you some time.

Comment: i think i would use that plugin for sure because i have to implement those features too.